# Can report Parameter name be accessed within report body?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with a set of input values for a parameter.I have used a drop down for showing the list of input which are basically an id field and a name field.Now when i select one input from the drop down i get the id field which is passed as input for other quarries.
But my problem is that i further need the name field of the selected item in the report body.
Is there any way to do this other that creating a separate dataset and passing the is to that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a parameter value to any part of a report that will accept an Expression field (such as a Textbox, Tablix cell, etc) by editing the expression to be:

```
=Parameters!ParameterName.Value
```

- or by selecting the appropriate parameter from the Item pane of the Expression dialog.

You can display the name field (instead of the parameter ID value) by changing `Value` to `Label` - like so:

```
=Parameters!ParameterName.Label
```